# Create a table in DynamoDB with 2 "columns" as a key (composite keys)

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create a table in DynamoDb with 2 "columns" as keys.

Consider this table example of MYSQL:

```
create table users_activities(
    `ACTIVITY_ID`            bigint(20)   NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `USER_ID`                bigint(20)   NOT NULL ,
    `DATE_CREATED_ON`        bigint(20)   NOT NULL ,
    `ACTIVITY_TEXT`          nvarchar(120),
    primary key(  `ACTIVITY_ID`, `USER_ID`)
);
```

I need to map this table to DynamoDB. How would you suggest I do it ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've mentioned in the comments, a single user_id can map to multiple activity_ids. This is a perfect scenario for using range keys.
Create a users_activities table in DynamoDB with USER_ID as hash key and ACTIVITY_ID as range key. Note that you always need to provide the hash key in your get/query calls to DynamoDB. In other words, you won't be able to perform querying by *just* activity_id without scanning the entire table.

In addition to the above, you might want to use date_created_on as your [local secondary index](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LSI.html)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I basically want the combined values of Acitvity_id and User_id to be unique. Can you tell me how I can achieve this using approach 1 ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by combined values. Since activity_id and user_id are PKs, won't their 'combined value' always be unique? Are you saying you want a single key to represent both activity_id and user_id (like Mike Kobit has mentioned in his solution)?

Comment: Yes. So each user_id can have multiple activity_ids in the table.

Comment: changed the question title.

Comment: Oh, in that case my understanding of your question was wrong. In this case, all you need to do is use user_id as a hash key and activity_id as  a range key. I'll edit my answer appropriately.

Comment: My question title was misleading. Sorry for that. The solution seems perfect. Thanks for that.

Comment: @shridharama What about the fact ACTIVITY_ID is declared as auto increment?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache That is an attribute of the MySQL table, so it shouldn't make a difference to DynamoDB.

Comment: The question is how to map the table to DynamoDB. DynamoDB doesn't support auto increment fields. Your answer is missing this point.